# Increment timestamp in Hive for same combination of records

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a dataset in hive table

```
input1,input2,input_time
key1,val1,2017-02-03 00:00:00
key1,val1,2017-02-03 00:00:00
key1,val2,2017-02-03 00:00:00
key1,val2,2017-02-03 00:00:00
key2,val1,2017-02-03 00:00:00
```

Columns(input1,input2) will form unique combination record. For the same unique combination, I want to increment input_time column i.e "2017-02-03 00:00:01" with seconds.

For the same combination say I have 65 records, once second reaches 59 seconds, it should increment (minutes + seconds) i.e "2017-02-03 00:01:01"

How do we increment time for the same combination of records, is it possible in hive?

```
Expected output:
input1,input2,input_time
key1,val1,2017-02-03 00:00:01
key1,val1,2017-02-03 00:00:02
key1,val2,2017-02-03 00:00:01
key1,val2,2017-02-03 00:00:02
key2,val1,2017-02-03 00:00:01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function to generate a temporary index for each row that you will be adding.

```
select 
   k, v , unix_timestamp(ts) as ts, 
   row_number() over ( partition by k,v ) as rn  
from ts_test
```

This will generate :

```
+----+----+----------+---+
|   k|   v|        ts| rn|
+----+----+----------+---+
|key1|val1|1486101600|  1|
|key1|val1|1486101600|  2|
|key1|val2|1486101600|  1|
|key1|val2|1486101600|  2|
|key2|val1|1486101600|  1|
+----+----+----------+---+
```

Now you can go ahead and add that to your time string, since it's already in ISO format.

```
SELECT a.k, a.v, from_unixtime(ts+rn) as newts from 
   ( select k, v , unix_timestamp(ts) as ts, row_number() over ( partition by k,v ) as rn  
from ts_test )a 

+----+----+-------------------+
|   k|   v|              newts|
+----+----+-------------------+
|key1|val1|2017-02-03 00:00:01|
|key1|val1|2017-02-03 00:00:02|
|key1|val2|2017-02-03 00:00:01|
|key1|val2|2017-02-03 00:00:02|
|key2|val1|2017-02-03 00:00:01|
+----+----+-------------------+
```

This can also be achieved in a single select as stated by @DuduMarkovitz :

```
select 
   k, v , 
   from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(ts) + row_number() over ( partition by k,v order by v asc ) ) 
from ts_test
```

Comment: **(1)** The OP have provided a good data sample, please don't ignore the columns names he gave. **(2)** No need for sub-query.

Comment: The above solution worked.. But for the combination, if try sorting based on v column ascending, it is not supported in partition clause. select k, v , unix_timestamp(ts) as ts, row_number() over ( partition by k,v order by asc ) as rn  
from ts_test

Comment: You're missing `v`. Shouldn't it be `order by v asc`?